# Build Bot package without provisioning

Tags: node.js, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to build a Bot for MS Teams using TeamsFX extension for Visual Studio. I've started from the demo and so far (not without excruciating pain) managed to get my functionality implemented.

Now I want to deploy my Bot to AWS (not Azure) so I want to build the Bot Package with its manifest but when I choose "Build Teams Package" I get the following error:

```
[2021-08-18T17:59:50.918Z] [Info] - [core] start task:executeUserTask, inputs:{"projectPath":"/Users/teamsapp","platform":"vsc","vscodeEnv":"local","function-dotnet-checker-enabled":{}}
[2021-08-18T17:59:50.920Z] [Debug] - [core] success to aquire lock on: /Users/teamsapp/.fx
[2021-08-18T17:59:50.986Z] [Debug] - [core] success to get questions for executeUserTask
[2021-08-18T17:59:50.987Z] [Error] - [Teams Toolkit] Teams Package build failed!
[2021-08-18T17:59:51.043Z] [Debug] - [core] persist project setting file: /Users/teamsapp/.fx/settings.json
[2021-08-18T17:59:51.044Z] [Debug] - [core] lock released on /Users/teamsapp/.fx
[2021-08-18T17:59:51.044Z] [Info] - [core] finish task:executeUserTask
[2021-08-18T17:59:51.044Z] [Error] - code:AppStudioPlugin.TeamsPackageBuildError, message: Teams package build failed. You must run 'Provision in the Cloud' first to fill out certain fields in manifest.
```

How can I build the teams app package?

Comment: We tried it using TeamsFX and it worked fine for us. Could you please check if all the fields in manifest are Updated? I hope you are following all the required points as mentioned in [Create a Microsoft Teams app package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/apps-package).

Comment: I decided to manually create the manifest file with App Studio as TeamsFX wasn't helpful at all, how can an error message be so vague to say "...to fill out certain fields in manifest."??

Answer (score 0):

We tried it using TeamsFX and it worked fine for us. Could you please check if all the fields in manifest are Updated? I hope you are following all the required points as mentioned in [Create a Microsoft Teams app package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/apps-package).